# unable to change my compile sdk version from 33 to 34

Tags: java, android, installation, version, project

In my android studio, I am unable to change my compile sdk version from 33 to 34. It doesn't show 34 option on compile sdk versions in program structure:
[image]

Comment: Do you have API 34 downloaded in your SDK Manager?

Comment: You don't need a UI simply change the value in Gradle config file.